# how do we set the default return value of select box to null in jquery

Tags: javascript, null, jquery-selectbox

If the selectbox is not selected then it will return null value, how does it possible?
I have tried this code:

```
<select name="city" id="city" style="width:238px;height:40px;"><option value= NULL >Select City</option>@foreach($cityName as $city)<option value="{{$city->id}}"> {{$city->name}}</option>@endforeach</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

jQuery will *always* get a string when it tries to read the value of a select element.

The closest you could come would be to use an empty string (`value=""`) or to test explicitly in JS:

```
var my_value = jQuery('select').val();
my_value = (my_value === "NULL") ? null : my_value;
```

Answer (score 0):

really simple ,I think it's just about html ,

```
<option value="" selected="selected"> ---- </option>
```

use this as a default selected item , and change the received value from "" to null in javascript if you want .